# Как правильно сделать уникальную выборку из 3 колонок из БД?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Есть выборка уникальных значений из БД по 3 колонкам

```
function getLocation($link){

    mysqli_set_charset($link, "utf8");
    $select = 'SELECT DISTINCT country FROM lost_animal';
    $query = mysqli_query($link, $select) or die(mysqli_error($link));
    $num = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if($num != '0'){
        for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++){
            $arr[] = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
        }
    }
    $select = 'SELECT DISTINCT city FROM lost_animal';
    $query = mysqli_query($link, $select) or die(mysqli_error($link));
    $num = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if($num != '0'){
        for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++){
            $arr[] = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
        }
    }
    $select = 'SELECT DISTINCT region FROM lost_animal';
    $query = mysqli_query($link, $select) or die(mysqli_error($link));
    $num = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if($num != '0'){
        for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++){
            $arr[] = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
        }
    }

    return $arr;
    die();
}
```

На клиентской стороне:

```
data = {action:'get_location'};
        $.post('inc/core.php', data, function(response){
            console.log(response);
                 obj = JSON.parse(response);
                $.each(obj, function(key, value){
                    console.log(value['city']);
});
});
```

Почему в консоле выдает undefined?

```
[{"0":"Latvia","country":"Latvia"},{"0":"Riga","city":"Riga"},{"0":"\u0420\u0438\u0436\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0439","region":"\u0420\u0438\u0436\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0439"},{"0":"riga","region":"riga"},{"0":"vot","region":"vot"},{"0":"Pildas iela","region":"Pildas iela"}]
index.php:45 undefined
index.php:45 Riga
4 index.php:45 undefined
```

И правильное ли решение, делать 3 запроса, чтобы выводить уникальное значение по 3 колонкам? Как бы сделали вы?

Comment: вообще один запрос, собирающий те что у вас через union. Но раз вы уж спросили, "как бы сделали вы"... Я бы сделал БД с нормальной (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0) структурой, т.е. справочники городов, регионов и стран

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому, что у вас не все элементы-json-объекты массива имеют ключ 'city'. Вы свалили все три уровня классификации в один массив, так в нём кроме городов есть страны и регионы, у них нет элемента 'city'.

Я наверно бы сделал древовидный json `[{"country":"Latvia", "regions":[{"region":"riga", "cities":[{"city":"Riga"}]}]}]`. или проще: `{"Latvia": {"riga": ["Riga",...]}}`

```
SELECT DISTINCT country, region, city FROM lost_animal ORDER BY country, region, city;
```

Далее при выборке отслеживаем изменения `country` и `region` и добавляем новые элементы на изменившемся уровне.